# How can I use public constants in other classes?

Tags: java

I'm trying to access a public constant variable outside my class and I don't understand why isn't working. I declared the variable `y` in this class:

```
package test;

public class TestConstant 
{
    public static final double y = 1;
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

It worked fine, I had the output `1` as expected.

Now I'm trying to access this variable outside my class:

```
package test;

public class TestConstant2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(y);
    }

}
```

I couldn't run the last source code. How can I use public constants outside a class it was declared in?

Comment: You access them like any other static field or method on a class: by prefixing it with the name of the class they are on: `TestConstant.y`.

Answer (score 3):

Constants live in the class where you defined them.

```java
package test;

public class TestConstant2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(TestConstant.y);
    }

}
```

Comment: And for completeness: if TestConstant would have been in an other package, `foo`, one would need to `import foo.TestConstant;`

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was testing right now

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the class name in front of the constant:

```
package test;

public class TestConstant2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(TestConstant.y);
    }
}
```

or import it with static

```
package test;

import static TestConstant.y;

public class TestConstant2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {       
        System.out.println(y);
    }
}
```

BTW: *static final* variables should be upper case

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the second code didn't work